# Ace tabs not drawn

Tags: jquery, ace-editor

I hope I can make myself clear enough for you to understand.

I'm trying to integrate ace into my site. The only problem is, if I use the tab key, the text won't relocate. Also, if I click inside to start editing, the character gets inserted 4 characters to the left. I think the `\t` character doesn't get drawn.

This is how it looks like now, but the `<h1>` and `<p>` tags should be indented by 1 tab (and selecting and editing behaves like the tab has been drawn).
[image: How it looks like]

Loaded ace files from src-min-noconflict in this order:

- ace.js
- mode-html.js
- theme-terminal.js

Code to activate the editor

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var editor = ace.edit('editor');

    editor.setTheme('ace/theme/terminal');
    editor.getSession().setMode('ace/mode/html');

    editor.getSession().setFoldStyle('manual');
    editor.setSelectionStyle('line');
    editor.setHighlightActiveLine(true);
    editor.setShowInvisibles(false);
    editor.setDisplayIndentGuides(true);
    editor.renderer.setHScrollBarAlwaysVisible(false);
    editor.setAnimatedScroll(false);
    editor.renderer.setShowGutter(true);
    editor.renderer.setShowPrintMargin(false);
    editor.getSession().setUseSoftTabs(false);
    editor.setHighlightSelectedWord(true);


    $('textarea[name="new_content"]').hide();
    editor.getSession().setValue($('textarea[name="new_content"]').val());

    $('form.form-textarea').on('submit', function(){
        $('textarea[name="new_content"]').val(editor.getSession().getValue());
    });
});
```

Css

```
#editor {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    font-family: Monaco, Menlo, 'Ubuntu Mono', Consolas, source-code-pro, monospace;
}
```

HTML

```
<textarea name="new_content" class="hide">{ filled by the server with html }</textarea>
<div id="editor"></div>
```

Comment: it seems to work fine here http://jsbin.com/ibocuj/1/edit

Comment: Strange... I forgot to mention I'm using twitter bootstrap, it just seems like the tab character gets overwritten or isn't drawn in the editor (does bootstrap do something like this?).

Comment: i am not aware of that, If you could make a demo reproducing this bug, i'll have a look

Comment: I had the same problem, and I don't know if it's caused by Bootstrap or not, but using `ctrl+}` and `ctrl+{` worked for me.